# How to prevent VSCode from removing tabs at the end of lines in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code

How to prevent VSCode from removing extra tabs at the end of lines in a CSV file ?

Comment: search if any auto-save functionality is setup

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by unchecking this box in the settings:

```
files.trimTrailingWhitespace
```